# How to create a window that is like default popup?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a browser action button. When the button is clicked, I need to do some computation and decide which window to open.

If I set `default_popup` in manifest.json, the popup looks like this.

[image: default_popup]

Since I need to do some computation and decide which window to open, I do in the following way.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    if(...)
        url="1.html";
    else
        url="2.html";
    chrome.windows.create({url:url, type: "popup"});
});
```

But the window created has border and is not at the button's position.

How do I create a window that looks like the default popup?

Answer (score 1):

If you dont figure out how to catch the event before the popup runs, you may do this (I do it for an extension of mine): Assuming both popups have the same width-height, always show popup1, and redirect (navigate to the other one) if it should show popup2. If you want to avoid flashing make sure both popups have fixed and equal body sizes.

Comment: It will be an option. I'm now curious whether chrome cheats at opening default popup; chrome can open a window without border but I cannot?

Comment: because such window is special, is part of the chrome interface and not an actual, fully-independant browser window. The window popup that you are creating with windows.create will have the browser border just like if you detach a tab.

Comment: OK. If I follow your suggestion, how can I run code when popup1 shows? I need to call `chrome.tabs.executeScript( {code: "window.getSelection()")` to get the selection of the current tab.

Comment: from a js script file in the popup page, which is included in the header of the popup1.html

Comment: at 0:36 you can see in action a popup changing from one page to another (and later navigating back to the first one, all within the chrome popup) http://youtu.be/ggYlsi5HoD4?t=27s